# Multilingual fetching in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, json, fetch, multilingual, decoupling

I need to fix a big issue about multilingual support in a decoupled Drupal React block.
Basic UI translations are based on i18next, and it works. Where it goes wrong is with the additional data that I’m fetching separately from the Drupal Rest API for mapping.

In my [carousel component](https://github.com/sinyayadynya/slider/blob/master/src/components/ToursCarousel.jsx) , I’m using something as:

```
const [showPosts, setShowPosts] = useState()
    const apiUrl = '/rest/slider-custom.json'

    let displayData
    async function pullJson() {

        const response = await fetch(apiUrl)
        const responseData = await response.json()
        displayData = responseData.map(function(tour) {
```

The problem is that `const apiUrl = '/rest/slider-custom.json'` is loading exclusively the default English translation and I looking for a way to add a language variable in front of the `/rest/slider-custom.json` path.

Thought that would be simple, but can't solve that with my novice state in React. Any hint most welcome!

Comment: how is the language determined?

Comment: By the browser url via 18next-http-backend.

Comment: @Breezer actually I'm able to render the langcode in the component with i18n.language, but don't know how to include it into the fetched url.

Comment: well if you just want to add it to your url `const response = await fetch(i18next.language+'/'+apiUrl)` ? or am i missunderstanding something here

Comment: @Breezer yes, `const response = await fetch(i18n.language+'/'+apiUrl)` work perfectly. Very simple. BTW how do you call that way of building url's?

Comment: "concatenating strings with variables" maybe the phrase you're looking for